# AngularJS $scope.$parent strange hierarchy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to access the $parent in my child controller but for some reason I have to access the Fifth $parent in order to get the actual $scope from the Parent controller, Any Ideas?

Parent Controller

```
angular.module('App')
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'user',
    function($scope, $rootScope, user) {

        $rootScope.currentNav   = 'home';
        $rootScope.currentUser  = user.data;

        $scope.tabs = [
            {
                heading     : 'Empresas',
                template    : 'home_companies_tab.html'
            },
            {
                heading     : 'Tickets',
                template    : 'home_tickets_tab.html'
            }
        ];

        $scope.companies = []

        $scope.selectedCompanyIndex = undefined;
        $scope.selectedCompany      = undefined;

        $scope.selectedTicketIndex  = undefined;
        $scope.selectedTicket       = undefined;

    }]);
```

Child Controller

```
angular.module('App')
.controller('HomeCompaniesTabController', ['$scope', 'Companies',
    function($scope, Companies) {

        $scope.loadCompanies = function () {

            $scope.companies = Companies.query();

        }

        /**
         * Init
         */

        $scope.selectCompany = function (company, index) {

            $scope.$parent.selectedCompanyIndex = index; //this doesnt work
            $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.selectedCompany      = company; //this does, why?

            console.log($scope);

        }

        if($scope.currentUser.security < 3) {

            $scope.loadCompanies();

        }

    }]);
```

Home template

```
<div ng-include="'dist/templates/header.html'"></div>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            company : {{selectedCompany}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <tabset>

        <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.heading}}">

            <div ng-include="'dist/templates/' + tab.template" ></div>

        </tab>

    </tabset>



</div>
```

Child template

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="HomeCompaniesTabController">

<div class="col-md-3">

    <h4>Lista de Empresas</h4>

    <hr/>

    <div class="list-group">

        <a
                href=""
                class="list-group-item"
                ng-repeat="company in companies"
                ng-click="selectCompany(company, $index)">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
                {{company.name}}
            </h4>
        </a>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-9">

    <div ng-show="selectedCompany">

        <h4><b>{{selectedCompany.name}}</b></h4>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent` is a completely crazy way to work with angular. Visually you can't see easily what that references. What if you insert a new level in the middle? Use a service to share the data and forget that `$parent` property even exists....you should almost never need it

Comment: It could be, but I will like to know why $parent is not working as it's supposed to

Comment: but that is exactly why you shouldn't use it. Are you sure you even have the right level? It is very simple to bind data through a service that is very easily traceable and is far more scaleable

Comment: by using a service, the parents don't update the templates

Comment: Then service is likely not set up properly

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: really simple demo I did for someone yesterday  http://plnkr.co/edit/qdvwrDPcyf4ij7VCbwRC?p=preview

Comment: much cleaner and easier to read isn't it?  Also can access same data anyhwere now

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments of charlietfl I came up with this simple service for sharing data

```
angular.module('App')
.factory('SharedData', [function () {

    return {

    }

}]);
```

Then I simply inject it in the controllers

```
angular.module('App')
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'user', 'SharedData',
    function($scope, $rootScope, user, SharedData) {

        $rootScope.currentNav   = 'home';
        $rootScope.currentUser  = user.data;

        $scope.sharedData = SharedData;

        $scope.tabs = [
            {
                heading     : 'Empresas',
                template    : 'home_companies_tab.html'
            },
            {
                heading     : 'Tickets',
                template    : 'home_tickets_tab.html'
            }
        ];

        $scope.companies = [];

    }]);
```